# Understand how to find interval of convergence for power series

Tags: calculus, power-series

Let $f(x)= \frac{3x}{1+x^2}$. The task is to first find a power series to represent this function, then find the interval of convergence.

We are given the power series representation of $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = 1 + x + x^2 + ...$ for $|x| < 1$, based on the convergence of the geometric series.

What I did to find a power series representation:

$$
f(x) = 3x \frac{1}{1-(-x^2)}
$$

Based on the power series representation of $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$ we can now use:

$$
3x \frac{1}{1-(-x^2)} = 3x \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-x^2)^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 3 (-1)^n x^{2n+1}
$$

But how to find the interval of convergence now?

The [solution to this Example 6.5 on Openstax Calculus 2](https://openstax.org/books/calculus-volume-2/pages/6-2-properties-of-power-series) says:

> Since the interval of convergence of the series for  $\frac{1}{1-x} $  is  $(−1,1)$,  the interval of convergence for this new series is the set of real numbers $x$ such that  $∣x^2∣<1$.  Therefore, the interval of convergence is  $(−1,1)$.

On the same page we were introduced to [Theorem 6.2: Combining Power Series](https://openstax.org/books/calculus-volume-2/pages/6-2-properties-of-power-series), but I can't make the connection between the interval of convergence from the new series and the original series.

Comment: You could use the ratio test

Comment: But do you have the ratio test or can you derive the interval of convergence from the fact that we know the interval of convergence of the simpler series, using the combination rules for power series (which is what the books solution does as far as I understand.)

Comment: Well I guess another way you can look at it is you can use the fact that the series $\frac{1}{1-x}$ converges on $(-1,1)$. You can easily deduce that $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ also converges on $(-1,1)$. The $3x$ in the numerator will not change this interval.

Comment: $\sum_i x^i$ converges to $\frac 1{1-x}$ for $|x| < 1$, and diverges for $|x| > 1$. Let $x = t^2$. Then $|x| = |t^2| < 1$ if and only if $|t| < 1$ Thus the radius of convergence for $\sum_ t^{2i}$ is also $1$.